# how can I get the majority (dominant) class of a raster to an area (polygon) using qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a vector layer with many basic units of planning (zones), a raster layer with three classes of geology and other raster layer of geomorphology with five classes.

How can I update the attribute table of the zones with their respective majority classes of geology and geomorphology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is referred to as **zonal statistics**. QGIS has a [zonal statistics plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) which, among other things, will compute the majority. Execute it on each raster layer and your attribute table should be propagated with the relevant statistics.

[image]

Comment: According to [this change](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/ee7b4d2539337f937aec9efae9ad603f8e2014ff) majority should be present in 2.10. What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Indeed, in the 2.10.1 version of  QGIS, the Zonal Statistics has been enhanced and now calculates: count, sum, average, median, standard deviation, minimum, maximum, range, minority, majority, and variance.